# Filter a ValuesQuerySet by a string?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I'm trying to achieve something like this by dynamically specifying the fields:

```
my_model.objects.values('id', 'name')
```

So I tried,

```
my_string = 'id', 'name'
my_model.objects.values(my_string)
```

but it doesn't work. But, this works :

```
my_string = 'name'
my_model.objects.values(my_string)
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Is this the correct way to pass values into .values() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Same as always](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
my_string = 'id', 'name'
my_model.objects.values(*my_string)
```

Comment: Thank you ! My in-experience in python is pretty obvious here.